# How to reference native function inside a class?

Tags: c#, c++, native, dllimport

I've got a dll, which exports function, which looks like this: `MyClass::MyMethod(char*)`.

How do I use that through DllImport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use DllImport, like this:

```
[DllImport("MyNativeC++DLL.dll")]
private static extern void MyMethod(StringBuilder myCharPointerParameter);
```

See [Passing char pointer from C# to c++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385783/passing-char-pointer-from-c-sharp-to-c-function)

Answer (score 0):

If `MyClass::MyMethod` is static, it can be exported and p/Invoked with ease (see Eric's answer).

If this is an instance method, things get a whole lot more difficult. [How to Marshal a C++ Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class).