# Passing char pointer from C# to C++

Tags: c#, pointers, pinvoke

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing char pointer from C# to c++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385783/passing-char-pointer-from-c-sharp-to-c-function)

I have this type of problem:

I have a c++ function with this signature:

```
int myfunction ( char* Buffer, int * rotation)
```

The buffer parameter must be filled with space chars ( 0x20 hex )

In C++ i can solve the problem simply doing this:

```
char* buffer = (char *)malloc(256);
memset(buffer,0x20,256);
res = myfunction (buffer, rotation);
```

I'm trying to call this function from C#.

This is my p/invoke declaration:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern unsafe int myfunction (StringBuilder Buffer, int* RotDegree);
```

In my C# class i've tried to do this:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(256);
buffer.Append(' ', 256);
...
myfunction(buffer, rotation);
```

but it doesn't work....

Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: "but it doesn't work" is not helpful.

Comment: You didn't even show the p/invoke declaration!  We can't help you without fundamental information like that.

Comment: @FrancisP This question is not a duplicate of that one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your p/invoke doesn't look quite right. It should (presumably) use the `Cdecl` calling convention. You should not use `SetLastError`. And there's no need for unsafe code.

I would write it like this:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int myfunction(StringBuilder Buffer, ref int RotDegree);
```

Then call it like this:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(new String(' ', 256));
int rotation = ...;
int retVal = myfunction(buffer, ref rotation);
```

I didn't specify the `CharSet` since `Ansi` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `rotation` by reference. You might also need to edit the signature of `myfunction`. Please let me know if the method works.

```
myfunction (buffer.ToString(), ref rotation);
```