# What C# datatype should I use to interface with unmanaged type "char* &sResult"

Tags: c#, .net, clr, pinvoke, unmanaged

I am writing a C# code, and there is a code that needs calling an unmanaged C++ library.

The signature in the library's header is like this

```
bool GetValueFromFile(char* sPathToFile, char* &sResult);
```

What signature should I translate this in C#? I tried:

```
bool GetValueFromFile(string filePath, ref string result)
```

But it does not work. There is no exception and the return value is true. But the string result stays null. It is the same for `out string result` or `StringBuilder result`.

I use Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer to get the function pointer as delegate.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993396/passing-char-pointer-from-c-sharp-to-c

Comment: @Sayse, I think the OP is asking about the refrence to pointer, which is not discussed in your linked question

Comment: @omerschleifer - I think you are correct but I think the solution may be the same (cdecl)

Comment: If the original function is 'char*&' this function will NOT populate your buffer - it will give you pointer to a buffer it has alreasdy allocated for you. So IntPtr is the the type of sResult, and then you'll need (sorry for not being specific but I cannot access documentation from here) some Marshal mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: @MiloszKrajewski is it like what Matthew Watson suggested in his answer? The problem is my sResult is unchanged from the initial pointer :(

Comment: @LouisRhys I've fixed an error in my answer below to do with using `out IntPtr` - please review it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle a reference to a pointer pretty much like a pointer to a pointer, at least as far as P/Invoke is concerned.

I think you will probably need to use an `IntPtr` for the `sResult` parameter, along with either [`Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx) or [`Marshal.PtrToStringAuto()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewyktcaa.aspx), but it's a bit difficult to say without knowing whether the C/C++ function allocates the string memory or not.

If it works, you will probably still need to free the memory (*after* getting the string) using [`Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freecotaskmem.aspx) or [`Marshal.FreeHGlobal()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx), but again this is impossible to know for sure without knowing what the C/C++ function does.

NOTE: If using an `IntPtr` to get an output value, you will need to use `out result` or `ref result`.

Comment: is it plain IntPtr, or ref IntPtr or out IntPtr for the sResult?

Comment: doesn't seem to work.. the IntPtr that I pass is unchanged from the initial value.

Comment: @LouisRhys Well is it an input or an output? Does the C/C++ function allocate the memory for the string, or is it expecting a non-null pointer? You can't write this without knowing (and telling us about) the exact requirements and effects of the function you're calling. Can you show the calling code?

Comment: It is written by a third party, so I don't knwo about whether the function allocate the memory or expect a non null pointer. But sResult is supposed to be an output. We pass a file path in `sPathToFile`, the library is supposed to do something in the file and send us the result in sResult.

Comment: @LouisRhys If you don't know what memory allocation the function is doing, how will you know how to free that memory? This is starting to sound a bit flakey... Anyway, an `IntPtr` is the lowest-level way you can pass pointers to and from C/C++. If it doesn't work with that (i.e. if the IntPtr value doesn't change) then nothing else will. `IntPtr` is marshalled as a pointer, and you can't go lower-level than that.

Comment: Oh also I just noticed that you're using `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer()` - why are you using that and not a normal P/Invoke declaration?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32321/discussion-between-louis-rhys-and-matthew-watson) because stackoverflow complains

Comment: @Matthew No, it's not plain `IntPtr`. It needs to be `out IntPtr` or perhaps `ref IntPtr` depending on the semantics.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah thanks, in his case I expect it will be `out`. I'll amend the answer. (Was clearly suffering from brainfade earlier ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass a pointer by reference. Assuming that `sResult` is passed from native to managed, i.e. that it has out semantics, here's the signature:

```
bool GetValueFromFile(string filePath, out IntPtr result);
```

Once you've called this you will need to convert it to a string:

```
IntPtr resultPtr;
if (GetValueFromFile(filePath, out resultPtr))
    string result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(resultPtr);
```

It's not clear who is responsible for freeing the memory that the native code allocates. Presumably that is documented somewhere and you already know how to handle that issue.